# Direction of shadows from my sun

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

Hi I have a scene with a fence as the single mesh. I have a HDRI as an environment texture and a sun lamp, to add some colour to my light. But the shadows from my fence don't point in relation to my sun. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Try to increase the brightness of the sun and/or decrease the brightness of the HDRI

Comment: Please share your blend file so that I can take a look at it? You can do this by uploading the blend file on this site - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and copy + pasting the generated url here. Please pack the external data and save the blend file before uploading.